# Tracks in a GPS file format

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, tracklog

How to fill a file with different GPS tracks so that when opened in a GPS track viewer the tracks appear simultaneuosly as different tracks? What GPS viewers do that?

Answer (score 1):

[EasyGPS](http://www.easygps.com/) will do that for you. You can add separate tracks to a new .gpx file and label them - make sure both the 'Label' and the 'Name on GPS' fields are filled out. Save the result and load it onto your unit.